# Templates and meta

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to pass some custom fields in a CPT to a post. I have some code, but I dunno how to "integrate" it.

I'm doing some stuff in a WP template (which is not mine, and this is the main problem).

**Code**

I have this **single-job.php**, which is -copy from single.php- post template for a CPT.

```
<?php
/**
 * Job Post
 */
if( defined('FW') ) :
    $elements = jevelin_option( 'post_elements' );
    if( jevelin_option( 'post_layout' ) == 'sidebar-left' || jevelin_option( 'post_layout' ) == 'sidebar-right' ) :
        $layout_sidebar = esc_attr( jevelin_option( 'post_layout' ) );
    endif;
else :
    $layout_sidebar = 'sidebar-right';
endif;

get_header();
?>

<div id="content" class="<?php if( isset($layout_sidebar) && $layout_sidebar ) : ?>content-with-<?php echo esc_attr( $layout_sidebar ); endif; ?>">
    <div class="blog-single blog-style-large">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'format-'.get_post_format() ); ?>


                    <?php /* Clear unclosed floats */ ?>
                    <div class="sh-clear"></div>


                    <?php /* Show page links navigation */ ?>
                    <?php jevelin_page_links(); ?>


                    <?php /* Show Tags */ ?>
                    <?php if( count( wp_get_post_tags( get_the_ID() ) ) > 0 ) : ?>
                        <div class="sh-blog-tags">
                            <h5><?php esc_html_e( 'Tags In', 'jevelin' ); ?></h5>
                            <div class="sh-blog-tags-list">
                                <?php foreach( get_the_tags( get_the_ID() ) as $tag ) :
                                    $term_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
                                ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>" class="sh-blog-tag-item">
                                        <?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

I also have this code that should pass my custom fields to the post text.

```
<?php
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
                    if($type == 'job'){
                        your-title();
                        your-requisitos();
                        your-description();
                    }

                endwhile;
                }   
?>
```

I've tried to "integrate" both codes in these lines but I don't know how to do it (it crashes).

```
<?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'content', 'format-'.get_post_format() ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_post_meta` is your friend.

> `get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )`
>
> Retrieve post meta field for a post.

Note that custom fields are named post meta internally.

e.g.

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key_1', true );
// Check if the custom field has a value.
if ( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $key_1_value );
}
```

Be warned though, it's tempting to store everything as a post meta, until you have to search for all posts with X meta with Y value. At this point X should have been a custom taxonomy, and your sites speed will tank massively.

Comment: Works great to get the meta. But It appears before the title ¬¬u I've also tried using the given example in content.php but appears in every post (well, I expected that)... I've tried (in content.php) this too

$args = array ( 
'post_type' => 'job',
);
 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your-title', true);
        }
 
    wp_reset_postdata();
 
} else {
 
echo 'Nothing found';
     
}

But also appears before

Comment: It appears where you place it, just as if you put an image at the top of a word doc it appears at the top. Look for the bit that outputs the title and put it afterwards not before

Comment: I understand... In single-job.php the "content" is here -->  get_template_part( 'content', 'format-'.get_post_format() ); ?>

So, i've created clone content.php into content-job.php, change that function to get_template_part('content-job',...) and trying. But this wild code appears... Any link/idea about where should I place my code? 

<?php
/**
 * Post format - Standard
 */

if( !isset($style) ) :
 $style = jevelin_post_option( get_queried_object_id(), 'page-blog-style' );
 
 
endif;

... (more code with other templates)